# Will rabbits come out of their hole on their own?

Tags: dont-starve

In the process of setting up a trap, I scared the rabbit I was trying to catch and he went into his hole.  Will he come back out or should I just move the trap?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rabbits will venture out of their holes, despite being scared into them.

Alternatively, if you're impatient, you can use a shovel to dig up the hole, forcing the rabbit out. However, this has the negative effect of there no longer being a renewable source of cute little critters for you to murder in your quest for survival.

It's worth noting that holes will continue to spawn rabbits even if you successfully trap one at that hole. This will allow you to reset your trap on the same hole after catching one.

Comment: I don't have a shovel yet.  That's why I wanted to know if they come out on their own.

Comment: +1 I always loved a "renewable source of cute little critters to murder" :D